# Text scaling issue with multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, gpu

I have recently acquired **Dell u2515h (2560x1440)**, and decided to setup a dual monitor environment with my current **LG W2453TQ (1920x1080)**. My plan was to use the dell monitor in portrait mode, but i noticed something strange after trying that: icons were a little stretched (i guess that's text scaling issue) on my LG monitor. Also: when I set both monitors in landscape, no problem occurred. The weirdest thing was: if I positioned the portrait oriented display (**u2515h**) from the right side, this problem disappeared, but when I positioned it from the left side of the landscape display (**W2453TQ**), then this problem occurred again. This is my first time writing here, and I just saw I cannot post images, to make things clearer. I would really appreaciate it if someone has an idea.

Things i tried and did: 
- installed both monitors' drivers 
- installed the latest gpu drivers 
- switched ports on my gpu (gtx 560) 
- switched ports on my monitors 
- fiddled with text scaling on my OS (Windows)